# Another Java classpath issue

Tags: java, classpath

I used Maven shade plugin to build the executable jar, which works fine when it include the properties in the build.

But when I tried to move properties out to a separate folder, it failed with `java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [app.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist`.

I have tried the following three methods, but all failed:

1. `java -cp "properties"` (or `".\*;properties\*"`) `-jar app.jar`
2. `SET CLASSPATH =.\*;properties\*`
3. or even put app.properties in the same path as app.jar

As you can see the path separator, I used Windows to run the jar.

[update]

I changed the shade config (from only `<mainClass>` to `<manifestEntries>`) as below, and it resolved the issue.

```
<transformer
        implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
    <manifestEntries>
        <Main-Class>com.lifeshield.reminder.App</Main-Class>
        <Class-Path>properties/</Class-Path>
        <Build-Number>0.1</Build-Number>
    </manifestEntries>
</transformer>
```

@Marko Živanović, thanks for pointing out the `-cp` and `-jar` usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use both `-cp` and `-jar` options.

If you use `-jar` then you have set classpath in manifest file. [More details](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html).

If you want to use `-cp` then you have to run application by specifying class name. [Details](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/classpath.html).